# Datatable is getting clear/replace with new data.add new data to datable data already exist in c#

Tags: c#, datatable

Here is my code. every time the dt_prices data table is getting cleared. trying to add a new row data table showing newly added row only. existing data is replaced with data.

I want all data should be shown in one data table(dt_prices). help me.

```cs
int temp=0;
DataTable dt_price = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < dt_Sec.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var Secuirty_Name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt_Sec.Rows[i]["M2MSecurityName"].ToString()) ? dt_Sec.Rows[i]["UnderlyingSecurityName"] : dt_Sec.Rows[i]["M2MSecurityName"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Secuirty_Name.ToString()))
    {
        DateTime Tradedate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt_Sec.Rows[i]["TradeDate"]);
        dt_Currency = GetSecurityCurrencywithWeights(Secuirty_Name.ToString());
        string currencyname = dt_Currency.Rows[0]["Currencyunitsymbol"].ToString();
        weightrate = GetWeightConversion(dt_Currency.Rows[0]["LotsizeUnit"].ToString(), BaseWeight) * Convert.ToDecimal(dt_Currency.Rows[0]["PriceQuoteWeightUnitNo"].ToString());
if(BaseCurrency == currencyname)
{
        dt_price = GetPriceData(Secuirty_Name.ToString(), Tradedate) 

}
else
{
dt_price =  GetConverisionPriceData(BaseCurrency, Tradedate, currencyname, Secuirty_Name.ToString());
}
        dt_price.Rows[temp]["PriceHigh"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dt_price.Rows[temp]["PriceHigh"].ToString()) * weightrate;
        dt_price.Rows[temp]["PriceLow"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dt_price.Rows[temp]["PriceLow"].ToString()) * weightrate;
        dt_price.Rows[temp]["PriceClose"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dt_price.Rows[temp]["PriceClose"].ToString()) * weightrate;
temp+=1;
    }
}
```

Above `dt_price` data is replaced with newly added data. So I won't want to replace the data. show entire data in datatable

Comment: `Secuirty_Name` Fixing typos makes code easier to read.

Comment: What is `temp`? Why does its value never change?

Comment: If dt_price is a datatable then this line doesn't make any sense : dt_price = BaseCurrency == currencyname ? GetPriceData(Secuirty_Name.ToString(), Tradedate) : GetConverisionPriceData(BaseCurrency, Tradedate, currencyname, Secuirty_Name.ToString());  You probably have dt_price defined as a var or object instead of a datatable so the compiler is not giving you an error.

Comment: i defined dt_price as DataTable dt_price = new DataTable();